# How to crop images using X Y, something is missing

Tags: php, image, crop

Argh where do i begin :) well i have currently installed jQuery select image area and i get X / Y positions so that works.

Now im trying to crop a image and it works perfectly when i select a area less than 103px it seems but if i select a larger area it doesnt crop how it supposed to do and only part of the area gets saved.

Why really and what am i missing? my output needs to be 103x103 px

Best Regards
John

```
$image_crop_x1 = $_POST['x1'];
$image_crop_x2 = $_POST['x2'];
$image_crop_y1 = $_POST['y1'];
$image_crop_y2 = $_POST['y2'];

$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(103, 103);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('../forum/temp/temp_avatars/1.jpg');

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, $image_crop_x1, $image_crop_y1, 418, 700);
imagejpeg($dest, "../forum/temp/temp_avatars/2.jpg", 100);
```

Comment: can you provide the value of var_dump($_POST) to see what actually those values are ?

Comment: array(6) { ["x1"]=> string(2) "18" ["y1"]=> string(2) "82" ["x2"]=> string(3) "392" ["y2"]=> string(3) "456" ["image_path"]=> string(32) "../forum/temp/temp_avatars/1.jpg" ["save_avatar"]=> string(12) "Spara Avatar" }

Comment: Shouldn't the `src_w` argument be calculated as `$image_crop_x2 - $image_crop_x1` ? same for `src_h` arg

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Chris?

Answer (score 3):

x2,y2 must be the higher point, when x1,y1 must be the lower point from the crop. Look this example:

[image: Example]

Where x = y = 103. There's no way x1,y1,x2 or y2 can be greater than 103. You need to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

This code works...

```
$image_crop_x1 = intval($_POST['x1']);
$image_crop_x2 = intval($_POST['x2']);
$image_crop_y1 = intval($_POST['y1']);
$image_crop_y2 = intval($_POST['y2']);

$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(103, 103);
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('../forum/temp/temp_avatars/1.jpg');

imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, $image_crop_x1, $image_crop_y1, $image_crop_x2, $image_crop_y2);
imagejpeg($dest, "../forum/temp/temp_avatars/2.jpg", 100);
imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($dest);
```

Comment: Same problem with this. Crop works works fine as long as i only select a area smaller than 103px, above that it gets messed up :(

Also seems to get messed up if a select a very small area on the image...